# How do I change Vim's internal pager to something else?

Tags: vim

Whenever I execute a command like `:imap`, Vim fires up some sort of (internal?) pager that doesn't support searching through the output.  Is there any way to configure Vim to use a different pager?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/655364/replacing-the-pager-inside-vim and https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5729/how-can-i-perform-a-search-when-vim-displays-content-using-more-pager/10472

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, but you can capture the output with the `:redir` command and then paste it into a buffer to search, filter, or whatever you like. For example,

```
:redir @a
:imap
:redir END
:new
:put a
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working solution:

[Redirect the output of a Vim or external command into a scratch buffer](https://gist.github.com/romainl/eae0a260ab9c135390c30cd370c20cd7)

Description of this script is in this answer for question:

[Can listings in the awful 'more' be displayed, instead, in a vim window?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49083560/1455694)

Described and used `scratch buffer` is similar to `less` command. Navigation and search function is available in it.

---

Checked in Vim with clipboard support:

VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Dec 07 2023 15:42:49)
Included patches: 1-213, 1840, 214-579, 1969, 580-1848, 4975, 5023, 2110, 1849-1854, 1857, 1855-1857, 1331, 1858, 1858-1859, 1873, 1860-1969, 1992, 1970-1992, 2010, 1993-2068, 2106, 2069-2106, 2108, 2107-2109, 2109-2111, 2111-2112, 2112-2269, 3612, 3625, 3669, 3741, 1847
under Ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo apt install vim
sudo apt install vim-gtk3
```

[apt - How do I install vim-gnome on Ubuntu 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208159/how-do-i-install-vim-gnome-on-ubuntu-19-10)