# Can listings in the awful 'more' be displayed, instead, in a vim window?

Tags: vim

In vim, neovim, when getting listings of mappings (eg :map), or when  looking at self-defined or system defined variables (:let or :set), the results are display in a 'more' pager window.

There is probably some dim-recesses-of-time reason why (in vim) 'more' is used to display data - not vim. But what I, and I think millions of others, would like to know is this: How to make it stop!(?)

If, because 'reasons', vim just cannot display this data - in vim - then how can some solution from the third millennium, such as 'less', be used instead of the awful 'more'?

Comment: vim does not use `more`.

Comment: If indeed you have an implementation that is using `more`, 10 to 1 says it's actually using $PAGER and defaulting to more.  Set your PAGER appropriately.

Comment: 1. Vim doesn't use an external pager; it uses an internal one. 2. `less` is from the same millenium as `more`. 3. On some systems, `more` is even actually `less`.

Answer (score 5):

You can `redir` Vim output, it's a bad system but it works.

```
redir @a
silent map
redir end
```

then open a new buffer and paste the contents of a in insert mode:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>

You could create a custom command for this too to make map a dynamic string input.

Answer (score 1):

To extend on Andy Ray's answer, here is [a custom command](https://gist.github.com/romainl/eae0a260ab9c135390c30cd370c20cd7) that will redirect the output of a Vim or external command into a scratch buffer:

```
function! Redir(cmd)
    for win in range(1, winnr('$'))
        if getwinvar(win, 'scratch')
            execute win . 'windo close'
        endif
    endfor
    if a:cmd =~ '^!'
        execute "let output = system('" . substitute(a:cmd, '^!', '', '') . "')"
    else
        redir => output
        execute a:cmd
        redir END
    endif
    vnew
    let w:scratch = 1
    setlocal nobuflisted buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe noswapfile
    call setline(1, split(output, "\n"))
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 Redir silent call Redir(<f-args>)
```

Usage:

```
:Redir hi         " show the full output of command ':hi' in a scratch window
:Redir !ls -al    " show the full output of command ':!ls -al' in a scratch window
```

`:Redir` in action:

[image: :Redir in action]

What it does:

1. Close any scratch window created by a previous execution of `:Redir`.
2. Grab the output the desired command.
3. Open a new buffer in a vertical window.
4. Make the new buffer a scratch buffer.
5. Insert the output of the desired command.

Comment: That is very nice. This scratch buffer is similar to `less`. Search function is working. Thanks for sharing.